# True Randomness/unpredictability in infinite quantum coin toss sequences?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality, determinism, randomness

In [Comments on indeterminism and undecidability](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2106/2106.08132.pdf) the abstract reads:

> "In a recent paper [1](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2106/2106.08132.pdf), it has been claimed that the outcomes of a quantum coin toss which is idealized as an infinite binary sequence is 1-random. We also defend the correctness of this claim and assert that the outcomes of quantum measurements can be considered as an infinite 1-random or n-random sequence. In this brief note we present our comments on this claim. We have mostly positive but also some negative comments on the arguments of the paper [1](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2106/2106.08132.pdf). Furthermore, we speculate a logical-axiomatic study of nature which we believe can intrinsically provide quantum mechanical probabilities based on 1(n)- randomness."

What grabbed my attention was something I read towards the end though:

> "Finally, we would like to mention an issue that weakens the argument of approach (i). If the locality and experimenters’ free will are assumed, it can be shown that Bell’s theorem rules out any algorithm that predicts experimental results even if algorithm is unknowable."

> "Now let’s choose a hidden variable which encodes this algorithm and assume that there are hidden universal Turing machines at points A and B. These Turing machines read the hidden variable when the particles arrive and output the measurement results. These outputs of Turing machines must obey Bell inequalities. This is obvious because such an algorithm and the hidden variable carrying it cannot transmit the spooky action at a distance. Since quantum mechanics can violate Bell’s inequalities, the sequence of outcomes it produces cannot be generated even by an unknowable algorithm. For this reason, the unknowable algorithm cannot save determinism under the assumptions of locality and free will."

But the problem is that I just finished reading a different paper named [Quantum Randomness: From Practice to Theory and Back](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ecristian/crispapers/QR_TP.pdf) and there I found this:

> "The “magic” of the quantum technology capable of producing unbreakable security depends on the possibility of producing true random bits. What does “true ran-domness” 5 mean? The concept is not formally defined, but a common meaning is the lack of any possible correlations. Is this indeed theoretically possible? The answer is negative: there is no true randomness, irrespective of the method used to produce it. The British mathematician and logician Frank P. Ramsey was the first to demonstrate it in his study of conditions under which order must appear (see [24, 32]); other proofs have been given in the framework of algorithmic information theory [9]"

And this:

> "Randomness means unpredictability with respect to some fixed theory. The quality of a particular type of randomness depends on the power of the theory to detect correlations, which determines how difficult predictability is (see more in [4, 6]). For example, finite automata detect less correlations than Turing machines. Consequently, finite automata, based unpredictability is weaker than Turing machine, based unpredictability: there are (many) sequences computable by Turing machines (hence, predictable, not random) that are unpredictable, random, for finite automata. In analogy with the notion of incomputability (see [15]), one can prove that there is a never-ending hierarchy of stronger (better quality) and stronger forms of randomness."

So my confusion is this: It is claimed that no algorithm can produce the quantum results because it is ruled out by Bell's theorem. But the other paper states that basically no real number is totally random, and any sequence can be predicted/generated by some unknown algorithm. So this seems like contradiction. I don't know what I'm not seeing/missing.

Comment: Note that Bell's theorem only rules out SOME quantum phenomena from being reproduced using classical physics.

Comment: It's important to distinguish between finite & infinite sequences. It's trivial to generate any finite sequence, so we generally don't consider a finite sequence to be random unless its complexity is high. See   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

Comment: There is no such thing as a quantum coin. That's simply a made up system that doesn't exist in nature. Nothing stops you from doing that, of course, but you aren't going to learn anything about reality using such models.

Answer (score 0):

„It is claimed that no algorithm can produce the quantum results because it is ruled out by Bell's theorem.”

This is not true. Bell’s theorem only rules out some local hidden variables theories that obey a certain assumption (the hidden variables and the settings of the detectors in a Bell test are independent variables). The rejection of that assumption allows you to construct local, hidden variable, deterministic theories such as ’t Hooft’s cellular automaton interpretation.

We also have a deterministic interpretation of QM that does not involve hidden variables (Deutsch-Hayden many worlds interpretation).

Non-local deterministic interpretations also exist (Bohmian mechanics).

It is worth noting that only deterministic theories can be local (EPR argument). This is a very powerful argument in favor of determinism.
In conclusion, there is no incompatibility between QM and determinism. In fact, non-deterministic theories are pretty much ruled out by EPR since they have to be non-local and hence, incompatible with Special Relativity.

Comment: Many worlds of any flavor is simply a misunderstanding of quantum mechanics and ruled out both by observation and trivial requirements for the word "science". t'Hofft admits that he can't actually reproduce physics. At least that's a lot more honest than Everett and his followers. Bohmian mechanics is nothing but an extra hard way of calculating the solutions of the Schroedinger equation that requires a non-physical entity to be introduced that does not allow for any backreaction (i.e. none of the usual conservation laws hold).

Comment: @FlatterMann, What is your proposal then?

Comment: My general "proposal" is to take Copenhagen seriously. It is actually trying to tell us something non-trivial about nature. I have been around the quantum mysticism block a couple of times... only to discover that the only real problem we have with quantum mechanics is an educational one: our QM courses and books emphasize the solution theory of the Schroedinger equation so much that all physics is lost. This is especially hard on those theorists who don't like to spend any time in the laboratory. They start looking for explanations in a formalism that was designed to not contain them.

Comment: @FlatterMann, Copenhagen is non-local, this is my problem with it. Even QFT is non-local in regards to measurement/collapse. At least, I was not able to find a local/relativistic treatment of collapse. Of course, you can chose Copenhagen over Bohm, but if you want locality you need to go for either many worlds or superdeterminism.

Comment: Why is Copenhagen non-local (I am not talking about the non-relativistic SE here, merely about the structure of the interpretation)? Or QFT? They are both non-separable, but that's not the same as non-locality. Locality lives in physical space, separability lives in Hilbert space. There is no such thing as collapse. One can't even find a useful definition of that word in the physics literature for all I know. See, this is exactly what I mean by "poor teaching". People are throwing a lot of useless words around instead of giving physical explanations that match the actual observations.

Comment: @FlatterMann, as mentioned in my answer, all non-deterministic approaches are non-local as per EPR argument. If the measurement in lab A is genuinely random it cannot be predicted from B. But, in the EPR setup you can, so, the A measurement must be determined. From here you can go local (both measurements were determined  - hidden variables) or non-local (the A measurement was determined directly by the B measurement, which, if the measurements are space-like, requires a ftl signal). You need a way to get from a superposition state to the observed results, that's the collapse.

Comment: Copenhagen is not non-deterministic. I don't even know what "genuinely random" is supposed to mean. We can talk about "statistically independent" within the limits of measured frequencies. Do you know about an experiment that can prove that such violations of statistical independence exist? Entanglement experiments certainly do not show that. They are not even designed to show that. Quite the opposite. The individual quantum system does not have a state. Only the ensemble has a state. That is one of the major misunderstandings of Copenhagen.

Comment: @FlatterMann, if Copenhagen is deterministic what is the equation that determines the measurement results? If the individual system does not have a state how exactly is this non-state able to determine the observed results? Can you provide some reference for this? Statistical independence is violated when there are interactions between subsystems. The positions of Earth and Sun are correlated/not independent due to the gravitational interaction.

Comment: Copenhagen is uncertain. Nothing determines an individual measurement result. It can not be determined because nature itself does not know the outcome, which depends on the experiment itself. Take two Stern-Gerlachs in series but rotated by 90 degrees: one splits the electron beam in up and down states. The second one splits each beam into two, again. What spin state were the individual electrons in initially? See the problem? It makes absolutely no sense to talk about something like a classical state for the individual system.

Comment: @FlatterMann, you contradict yourself. If nothing determines the measurement result, the theory is non-deterministic, yet you claimed above that it is NOT non-deterministic. So, which is it?

Comment: The change in state of the ensemble is perfectly predictable. That is what Copenhagen does. It does require the input of the specific experiment, though. That's why it has two parts: the evolution of the free ensemble and the specification of the experiment using the Born rule. What Copenhagen does not predict is the outcome of a measurement on an individual system. Something being uncertain is simply not the same as something not being deterministic. The periphery of quantum mechanics is, unfortunately, littered with false dichotomy fallacies. This is yet another one.

Comment: @FlatterMann, determinism means that the past state uniquely determines the outcome. As you admit, this is not true in Copenhagen, so the theory is nondeterministic.

Comment: The change in state of the ensemble is deterministic, right up to the measurement, which choses which possible outcomes we want to see. Neither the theory nor nature can know that. There is no other state in quantum mechanics. There are other interpretations that are desperately trying to restore individual state in a classical sense. They all fail.

Comment: @FlatterMann, so Copenhagen is indeterministic, therefore, as proven above, non-local. Given the large amount of evidence for locality we can conclude that the Copenhagen interpretation can be pretty much ruled out. What remains (local, deterministic interpretations) are more likely to be true.

Comment: Copenhagen males perfectly deterministic statements about "state". "State" in Copenhagen is simply not what most people think "state" means. That's an educational, not a physical problem. We can agree that the state of education about quantum mechanics is absolutely horrendous and has been for over a century. I am trying to change that right now. That change happens to be hard, though, because once misconceptions have been thoroughly established, they are nearly impossible to remove.

Comment: @FlatterMann, I don't care about the state, which as you said, is just a statistical description of an ensemble. As the EPR argument above proves, the only way for the theory to be local is for the individual measurement results at A and B to be determined. Copenhagen rejects this, so it cannot be local. There is a version of Copenhagen, Consistent histories, where the spin of the particles is predetermined, but that theory has other issues.

Comment: Quantum mechanics is perfectly local. It's just not separable. Copenhagen makes no statement about locality. It doesn't say that a measurement is determined. The individual measurement is simply uncertain. The only thing that is determined is the quantum mechanical ensemble and even then we have to throw the measurement in. That's because the measurement is not an abstract but a physical process that changes the outcome. What is so strange about that?

Comment: @FlatterMann, there is a logical argument that proves you wrong, "If the measurement in lab A is genuinely random it cannot be predicted from B. But, in the EPR setup you can, so, the A measurement must be determined.". Unless you can show this argument to be unsound it doesn't matter what Copenhagen states. It's non-local.

Comment: The measurement at B can not be predicted from A because both are free choices of the physicists who perform them. If you know both measurements, then you can predict the correlation between the outcomes at A and B, but that's just conservation laws at play. There is absolutely nothing special about that in QM. You can play that game with left and right socks. That is not what the word "non-local" means.

Comment: @FlatterMann, Both measurements are performed on the same axis, so they are always anti correlated. Yes, it's like "left and right socks". The thing is the color of the socks is predetermined. If it's not, it doesn't work. To see it better I can reformulate the argument. After the A-measurement (say the result is Z-UP) the state of B is Z-DOWN. If the A measurement did not disturb/change B (locality) it logically follows that the state of B had to be Z-DOWN even before the A measurement, otherwise it changed. So, the spin of the particles (on Z) was already determined before measurement.

Comment: Conservation laws are the consequence of the absence of a symmetry breaking mechanism. You are basically just hunting a snark. What causes "entanglement" is literally NOTHING. Yes, nothing has severe consequences. All of relativity is the consequence of the emptiness of the physical vacuum. So is quantum mechanics.

Comment: @FlatterMann, my argument does not depend on any assumption about the origin of conservation laws, so nothing you said is relevant in regards to its validity.

Comment: Emmy Noether would probably ask you to hold her beer. There is no entanglement in systems that are subject to external interactions. It's lost immediately.